# SQL Server, filter for max date and max date minus 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, max

I'm trying to design a view and apply several conditions on my timestamp (datetime): last date and last date minus 7 days. 
This works fine for the last date:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table)
```

I couldn't figure out the way to add minus 7 days so far.

I tried, for instance

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table)) OR (timestamp = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -7, MAX(timestamp)) FROM table)
```

and some other variations, including GETDATE() instead of MAX, however, I'm getting the execution timeout messages.

Please let me know what logic should I follow in this case.

[Data looks like this, but there's more of it :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88FC3.png)

So I want to get data only for rows with 29/11/2019 and 22/11/2019. I have an additional requirement for filtering for factors, but it's a simple one.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with the next code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table    
WHERE (timestamp >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, GETDATE()) AS datetime)) AND (timestamp < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)) OR
                 (timestamp >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 8, GETDATE()) AS datetime)) AND (timestamp < CAST(DATEADD(day, - 7, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)) AND (Factor1 = 'Criteria1' OR
                 Factor2 = 'Criteria2')
```

Not sure if it's the best or the most elegant solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about dates, then perhaps you want:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select max(timestamp) as max_timestamp from t) tt
where (t.timestamp >= convert(date, max_timestamp) and
       t.timestamp < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, max_timestamp))
      ) or
      (t.timestamp >= dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, max_timestamp)) and
       t.timestamp < dateadd(day, -6, convert(date, max_timestamp))
      );
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please clarify, what is "tt" and why do you cross join max_timestamp, if later there is no reference to it? Also, convert(date, ...) doesn't seem to work for me, I guess I'll need to use varchar(103), but it's confusing to me, as in dateadd "day" is already specified, what's the reason to convert it?

Comment: @ako . . . That is a really good question.  I fixed the references.